# How to define a setter for bracket operator?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have this class:

```
struct testy {
    std::array<int, 10> data;
    float operator[] (int idx) const        { return 1 / data[idx]; }
    float &operator[](int idx)              { return ??? }
};
```

What I want to happen is for example, when I write

```
testy Pineapple;
Pineapple[1] = 0.1;
```

then what would actually happen is

```
Pineapple.data[1]= 1 / 0.1;
```

I started writing the bracket overloads and then realized that the second one that returns by reference cant actually do any logic to transform the data itself so I'm kinda stumped here.

Yes, I know I could just write a setter function but that array will be heavily used by various algorithms and I'd like to make accessing it as convenient as possible from the coding side.

Comment: just assign 1/0.1 to data[1], in the operator [] overload, why make it complicated?

Comment: As mentioned by @MosheRabaev, that's probably the way to go. However, if you insist, you can use a proxy class, so your `operator[]` will return the `Proxy`, then overload the assignment operator of the `Proxy`. But, IMO, way too complicated.

Comment: @MosheRabaev: Because that makes no sense as a thing to do, and would be completely unexpected behavior from users of the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way is to use a proxy for testy elements:

```
struct testy {
    std::array<int, 10> data;
    float operator[] (int idx) const        { return 1.0 / data[idx]; }
private:
    struct element {
        int &el;
        element(int &a) : el(a) {}
        operator float() const { return 1.0 / el; }
        float operator=(float val) const {
            el = 1.0/val;
            return val; } };
public:
    element operator[](int idx) { return element(data[idx]); }
};
```

Comment: was initially concerned over the performance overhead but dang! gets optimized away nicely, 0 difference from using a function setter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic solution with a proxy class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct testy; // forward declaration

class proxy
{
private:
    testy& _t;
    int _idx;
public:
    proxy(testy& t, int idx): _t(t), _idx(idx) {}
    proxy& operator=(double val);
    operator double() const; // conversion to double
};

struct testy {
    std::array<double, 10> data;
    double operator[] (int idx) const { return 1 / data[idx]; }
    proxy operator[](int idx)        {return proxy(*this, idx);}
};

proxy& proxy::operator=(double val)
{
    _t.data[_idx] = 1. / val;
    return *this;
}

proxy::operator double() const
{
    return _t.data[_idx];
}

int main()
{
    testy Pineapple;
    Pineapple[1] = 0.1;
    std::cout << Pineapple[1] << std::endl;
}
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1692fdd0a6fdaa8)</kbd>

Comment: Wow, and after you have wrote such or similar code someone someday after you should maintain it. LOL Is it possible that C++ in it's all awesome can't do this simply in one line ?

Comment: @SoLaR A mess, I agree, but unfortunately currently I'm not aware of any way of cleanly overloading setters and getters. The "proxy" pattern is relatively well known. But you're right, it took me a while today to realize what I wrote 6 years ago :))

Comment: Is it okay to return the proxy as a reference? Since you're creating the proxy inside the function context, wouldn't it "have no place to be" when the function returns?

Comment: @JerônimoNunes That's ok, since `Pineapple[1]` returns a `proxy&`, then the `proxy&` applies the `operator=`, which modifies the `Pineapple` instance (captured inside the temporary proxy by reference). So the proxy reference is still valid, and it will be valid until the end of the statement (that ends with `;`). We want this behaviour since we may want to chain `proxy::operator=(double)` together, like `(Pineapple[1]=0.1)=0.2;` Note that we are not using the proxy returned by reference anywhere after the end of the statement.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment